# How to vertically center text span in fixed position div?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a div with `position: fixed;` whose height changes according to height of browser window. And I want to horizontally center text span inside that div. How can I accomplish this using just CSS? (Also, I want to make it IE8 compatible.)

```
#fixed_div{
    position: fixed;    
    top: 40px; 
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 40px;
}

#text_span{
    /* ??? */
}
```

Comment: Is the text is in single line or multiple line?

Comment: ..and do you want to center the text horizontally or vertically? you mentioned vertically in the title but in the post you said horizontally.. :/. Please make your post clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top: 50% trick won't be precise, since it will be a little lower, there are couple of tricks:

1. Span position is absolute, top is 50% AND margin-top -> -50% of the span height (can try with %, preferably with the height of the span if it's known).

   ```
   #text_span {
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       margin-top: -50%; //or pixels (according to Mr. Green it has to be pixels)
       width: 100%;
       text-align: center;
   }
   ```
2. Wrap the span with a div that has display: table, and the span is display: table-cell

   ```
   #wrapper-div {
       display: table;
       height: 100%;
   }
   #text_span {
      display: table-cell;
      width: 100%;
      vertical-align: middle;
   }
   ```

Working fiddle for the table method: (it doesn't work on the fixed element directly, you have to add another element inside) http://jsfiddle.net/a4ndeza5/1/

Hope this helps.

Comment: `margin-top: 50%` doesn't work since it renders related to the container. so, in your case top: 50% will bring the element 50% bottom and again after doing margin-top: -50%, it will go again to the default position. _according to the logic_. but margin-top value in percentage is based on width but not height. and to your second method, nothing happens if you apply display: table-cell to a position: fixed element. So, your both cases fails..

Comment: The display: table-cell isn't on a fixed positioned element, it's on the span which isn't fixed.

Also I did write you might have to put the margin-top in pixels...

Comment: display table doesn't work on the fixed element directly, you have to add another element inside, working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a4ndeza5/1/